# how to get the integer part of a real number that is positive using only basic arithmetic

Tags: algorithm, math

This is a question for school, reinventing the wheel as usual.

I'm allowed to use basic arithmetic `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and comparison, but I'm obviously not allowed to use cast.

The method has to be efficient, so I thought about multiplying a variable by 2 until it's bigger then do a dichomitic search between the powers of 2 that contains the real number I want to extract the integer part.

However, in the next section, I'm not allowed to use these basic arithmetic and comparison between integer and float, only between 2 integers, or 2 floats.

I can't find any solution to this...

Comment: Do you know anything about the bounds of your inputs? You can search for two integers that bookend the value via something like a binary search. Is that in the spirit of the question?

Comment: so my only input is r which is a float number, and i want to get the integer part of r without using cast, and inputs of arithmetics operations must be of the same type. the idea is to find an integer n that verify this : n <= r <= n+1 but i actually found a way to solve my proble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow your idea of multiplication by two to surpass the value then dichomitic search (aka binary search) to get the desired integer. However, since you are not allowed to compare a float with an integer, start with *two values*, the float `1.0` and the integer `1`. Do all your multiplications and comparisons with the float value, then at each step whatever you do to the float value you also do to the integer value. So at any point, your float value and your integer value are equal, and you are using the float value for all comparisons with your given value.

So if your given value is `3.1416`, you start with your initial guess values of `1.0` and `1`. `1.0` is less than `3.1416`, so you double both guesses and get `2.0` and `2`. The float `2.0` is still less than `3.1416` so you double both guesses again and get `4.0` and `4`. Your float guess `4.0` is finally too high, so you use binary search and try `3.0` and `3`. The float guess is low. However, your integer guess `3` is just one away from your previous integer guess of `4`, so you are done. The final integer result is thus `3`.